# Why is my very simple Python script failing?

Tags: python, urllib2

`noob.py` here. I'm trying to fetch content from a page but the `print` statement raises an error I don't understand.

Actual code:

```
import urllib2
import sys

url = "http://make.wordpress.org/core/page/2/"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read
print html
```

The output:

```
$ python get.py
<bound method _fileobject.read of <socket._fileobject object at 0x3722ec9a8d0>>
```

I suspect there is something Python doesn't like about that particular URL because it works with, say, `http://www.python.org` instead, but I can get any useful info to understand that.

What I don't get either is that, if I enclose this within a `try:` and `except:↵ pass`, I still get that error message.

Any pointers much liked.

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful. I feel really better knowing this.

Comment: @Ozh Not sure if sarcasm or just extremely grateful.

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND: extremely sarcastic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not an error; it is a string representation of the `read` method.

You are seeing it because on this line:

```
html = response.read
```

you forgot to invoke the `read` method.  So, `html` is assigned to the method itself, not its return value.

Adding `()` after the method name will invoke it:

```
html = response.read()
```

Now, `html` is set to the return value of the `read` method.

Comment: OMG. I knew I would feel dumb. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Good thing to learn here is that everything (functions, data, variables) in python is an object and `print <obj>` will give you something like `object at 0x3722ec9a8d0>`